# Scrolling issue on Windows Phone IE 10 (typing to inputs)

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, mobile, scroll, windows-phone

We've got two almost same forms. When it's in `div` with `overflow: auto` there is an issue with both `select`s and `input`s, when it's just put normally then works properly.

Two of them on top are working correctly, `select` on top sometimes also works correctly.

Problem is random:

- When you click on field - browser firstly scrolls to top, then a little below field, then a little above, and finally it goes to correct position
- Sometimes you can't click on field
- Sometimes there is no cursor shown
- Or when you are typing anything on keyboard `div` is scrolling down, even when there is nothing (so after typing a lot of times, you are below content and see just blank screen)

Probably it occurs also on mobile IE 11, but I can't check it.

Anyone had similar issues with mobile IE?